# Why does AudioQueueDispose throws strange exceptions from it's own framework?

Tags: ios, exception, core-audio, audioqueue

I am making an audio streaming application.
When I try to dispose the AudioQueue object, I get the exception shown on the screenshot.

I use

```
AudioQueueDispose(queue,true)
```

If I change true to false, exception is still thrown but a bit later.
If I use AudioQueueStop or any other stopping, resetting functions, I do not get this exception.

(With the help of a isStopping flag, I return from buffer callback function without touching to buffers if it is being stopped.)

Here is the screenshot:
[image]

I do not understand the problem, what am I missing here?

Comment: When do you call `AudioQueueDispose`? Do you use a property listener for `kAudioQueueProperty_IsRunning` property ?

Comment: I do not have any property listener. I checked it so I could try removing property listeners before disposing :-/ After hitting Stop Button, I set some flags to indicate that everything should stop. When everything stops (like buffer callback function etc..), the main loop exits. I call AudioQueueDispose after breaking that main loop which keeps player object alive.

Comment: Do you check that `kAudioQueueProperty_IsRunning` property equals zero after breaking that main loop and before calling `AudioQueueDispose` ?

Comment: @Emmanuel I was not using it. After your comment, I added `AudioQueueGetProperty( queue, kAudioQueueProperty_IsRunning, &property_running, &size );` added a `while(property_running){}` loop. It skips the loop as `property_running` returns `NO`. Afterwards I call `AudioQueueDispose`, but I still get the same exception.

Comment: Call `AudioQueueDispose` while AudioQueue still running may be source of problems, but that's not your case.

Comment: Hopefully the exception is a `CAException` try to set a breakpoint in CAException constructor, to see if the error code can help solving your problem.